# Problem with jquery-1.3.2.min.js JQuery

Tags: jquery

I was trying to add a Jquery file into my application and it gave me following error:

Warning      22      Error updating JScript IntelliSense: C:\Users\Desktop\jquery-1.3.2.min.js: Object doesn't support this property or method @ 18:9345

Geetha.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try opening it in a different browser - do you get an error? Which error? Which browser?
2. Try a newer version of jQuery - it may make the problem go away